# Is it possible to read the data exchange between my computer and a usb device in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, usb

Hi there I'm new to python I am tasked to write a python program to read the data that is sending from my computer to USB devices like a flash drive.

```
import win32com.client

wmi = win32com.client.GetObject ("winmgmts:")
for usb in wmi.InstancesOf ("Win32_USBHub"):
    print (usb.DeviceID)
```

However other than identifying the devices that are connected. I can't read what is going out of the USB port.
I understand it is possible to read it using a USB listener, is there any python library that is able to act as a USB listener?

Comment: have you tried using pywinusb library ?

Comment: I tried to use it but i didn't have any success with it. However I did notice that win32com is documented under pywin32.

Comment: I can see that in your code only DeviceID's are printed so it will display only the connected devices.

Comment: Yea this is my initial thoughts I should be able to get the DeviceIDs first and then be able to target the Devices I'm interested in